# Loop each cell until text = "timestamp" and then timestamp any changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm working on a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XpTC83kCJo1yWUc3f_OFeyrjsqy0zEW3axcHPZfQgO0/edit#gid=0) with multiple users collaborating. The spreadsheet admin asked me to create a timestamp for any new/changed entries; therefore, I cannot protect the range to prevent anyone from tampering with the timestamp column. Please note users will constantly add/remove rows (including adding rows above header) and columns so the "timestamp" column is always changing. Today the "timestamp" column is in cell E2 but tomorrow it can change to cell C4.

Below is my attempted code where I try to loop though each cell until it finds "timestamp" so that I can get the row & column number. But I am having issues with [my code](https://pastebin.com/H6kEQGN8).

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var thisSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var tf = thisSheet.createTextFinder("timestamp");
 
  // This finds Row # where cell = "timestamp"
  var thisRow = tf.findNext().getRow(); 
  // This is supposed to find Col # where it = "timestamp" but I'm having issues 
  var thisCol = tf.findNext().getColumn();
 
 
  var ss = e.source;
  var main_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sports_team');
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "sports_team") {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    main_sheet.getRange(thisRow, thisCol).setValue(currentDate);
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you find the timestamp cell after you change the content to new Date()?

Comment: You could store timestamps in notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion: Use `getCurrentMatch()` to find the column index

Calling the `findNext()` function again after the looking up the row index is expected to return a null value unless there's another cell with the value "timestamp" in the sheet. To get the column index after looking up the row index, I suggest using `getCurrentMatch()` instead.

I've made some modifications to your code to have it automatically add a date on the timestamp column when the sheet is edited. Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var thisSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sports_team");
  var tf = thisSheet.createTextFinder("timestamp");
 
  // This finds Row # where cell = "timestamp"
  var thisRow = tf.findNext().getRowIndex(); 
  // I used getCurrentMatch() to find the column index instead of findNext()
  var thisCol = tf.getCurrentMatch().getColumnIndex();
 
  //Finds the current active sheet
  var main_sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  //Finds the index of the row being edited
  var row = e.range.rowStart;

  if (main_sheet.getName() == "sports_team" && row > thisRow) {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    //Inserts the date on the row being edited, under the timestamp column
    main_sheet.getRange(row, thisCol).setValue(currentDate);
  }
}
```

Note that this code only inserts the date on the timestamp column if the cell/row being edited is below the timestamp header.

### Reference:

- [getCurrentMatch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#getcurrentmatch)

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thanks. 

Comment: I went ahead and attempted to modify the code so it can timestamp 2 sheets. https://pastebin.com/Y8ki5b1r

Answer (score 0):

I rather mindlessly modified the code without really thinking about it much.  But now that I have I don't understand how you find the timestamp cell after you change the content to new Date()?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "sports_team") {
    const mc = sh.createTextFinder("timestamp").getCurrentMatch();
    if(mc) {
      var r = mc.getRow();
      var c = mc.getColumn();
      sh.getRange(r, c).setNote(new Date());//I put the timestamp in the note 
    }
  }
}
```

With as much as you've got going on in that sheet I might have preferred storing the time stamp in PropertiesService or and ascii file.

One of the big problems with onEdit trigger and function is that it's quite slow and it sounds like you've got a bunch of users that don't really care. It may not be possible to satisfy the spreadsheet admin.

Comment: Thanks for attempting. I wanted the script to timestamp any changes under the cell "timestamp".